# What does it mean for velocity to be a derivative of position, if position a point, not a function?

Tags: kinematics, vectors, velocity, differentiation

So in mass-spring simulation I encountered that one simulates particles by using positions and velocities of particles etc.

People may say that velocity is the **derivative of position**.

But isn't "position" (in "common language sense") a point/place? I.e. it would be some e.g. $(x,y)$. But derivatives act on functions. This would suggest $(x(t),y(t))$, a tuple of functions.

**Q1:** Then what does "derivative of position" mean in in this context? Since $\frac{d}{dt} (x,y)$ would not make sense. Yet we're possibly interested in points $(x(t), y(t))=(x_0,y_0)$.

**Q2:** Also, where does the $(x(t),y(t))$ come from? How does one define these functions that give position?

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean. Position is a vector-valued function of time. So what the problem?

Comment: @Brick So you mean that I should've defined the position "function" somehow? Why cannot position be $(x,y)$, which is not a function?

Comment: Usually it's $(x(t), y(t))$, which is a vector-valued function of time.  If there's no motion then it's a trivial function (constant), but if there's motion, then the position changes with time.

Comment: "the position is a vector, e.g. (x,y), not a vector of functions (x(t),y(t))" 

you get from the simulation  $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ so your  position vector is now $\vec{R}=[x(t)\,,y(t)]^T$ and the  velocity is $\vec{\dot{R}}=[\dot{x}(t)\,,\dot{y}(t)]^T$

Comment: Why do you think being a vector and a function are mutually exclusive?

Comment: If position doesn't change with time, the problem you're trying to solve is probably very very easy.

Comment: Please edit the question and make it clearer what you are asking.

Comment: *position is intuitively a vector, not a vector of functions or vector function.* citation needed

Comment: @KyleKanos Well how about: a vector is a "place", a function is a "graph"? A position in common language is a place/point?

Comment: A position is a point, sure (or you can consider it an arrow pointing to a point). But the position might change in the next moment, it might be another point in the next instant. This change is what you catch with a derivative. This change is called velocity. While position is a point, if it changes in the next moment, then it changes over time. So you can draw out the points at different times - this is your function that can be drawn as a graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the position is [merely] a vector,...not a...vector function, then what does "derivative of position" mean in this context?

Formally, it's nonsense. It doesn't mean anything.  "Derivative" is an operation on a *function*. If a thing is not a function, then you can't talk about its derivative.

If somebody tells you that "velocity is the derivative of position," that's almost certainly an informal way of saying, "the velocity *function* is the derivative of the position *function*, with respect to time."

Comment: Yeah it seems that this is really just a case of sloppy language use.

Answer (score 4):

Position is typically a vector function of time. At each time, there’s a specific position vector value.

To take the derivative of this, you subtract those position vectors at small differences in time, yielding a position difference vector, divide that by the time difference to get a velocity vector, and take the limit to zero time difference.

Comment: I would not say "typically."  If you want to define the velocity of a particle at some instant, then you _must_ be able to describe its position as a function of time in the neighborhood of that same instant.